# Why is NULL allowed in List and not in Queue interface?

Tags: java, list, null, queue, addition

For starters, `List` is ordered collection that allows **null** elements to be inserted. On the other hand `Queue` is LIFO or FIFO collection that generally doesn't allow **null** elements. `LinkedList` implements both `List` and `Queue` and is thus only `Queue` implementation that allows **null** as element.

Suppose the reason behind not allowing **null** in `Queue` is that methods such as *poll()* or *peek()* can return **null** as:

- no more elements
- null as element

**This is common answer on stackoverflow to question "Why is null not allowed in Queue".*

Knowing the problem **null** can cause us in `Queue`, any programmer can make this logic:

```
if (!queue.isEmpty()){
    queue.poll();
}
```

Using logic I just provided we can easily tell that if we get **null** as return value, it will 100% be element' value and not **null** as empty queue. So I have to ask again, what is the true reason of not allowing **null** in `Queue`? Am I missing something else?

Comment: You can always use Optional's if you really want null elements.

Comment: I am more curious in a reason of such a decision than my own implementation. One rule I follow is: understand why something works and not just how it works ;)

Comment: I haven't found those reasons. Maybe comment so we can learn something from it?

Comment: The reason is the one you yourself provided: `poll` is designed to return `null` when there's no element left in the queue. Period. That's how it was designed and that's what we get. The fact that you can have a workaround for that is irrelevant.